# Java get metadata of public file on Google Drive

Tags: java, api, google-drive-api, metadata

Hello I've downloaded and installed the latest version of Drive REST API for java and want to get the metadata of a public file from Google Drive by the fileID - I have the following code:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "test";
private static final String FILE_ID = "theFileId";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    printFile(service, FILE_ID);
}


private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {

  try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();
      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
  }
}
```

But I get the error message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."

I've tried it on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get which worked out just fine.

Do I have to authenticate with an API key when the file is public and how would I do that if so.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to authenticate with an API key.  See the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-auth

Comment: But I can ignore the Client ID stuff right, or is that also required?